# How to groupby one value of a column in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, count

I have two columns that look like this:

```
Vehicle Brand      Reason of repair

Alfa Romeo         Brakes not working
Honda              Annual Service
BMW                Other
Alfa Romeo         Electrical issues
Honda              Paint
Alfa Romeo         Annual service
Alfa Romeo         Annual service
```

I want to group by only `Alfa Romeo` and count the `Reasons of repair`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you only care about one brand, just filter it with `loc` and get the [`value_counts()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
df.loc[df['Vehicle Brand'] == 'Alfa Romeo', 'Reason of repair'].value_counts()

# Annual service        2
# Brakes not working    1
# Electrical issues     1
# Name: Reason of repair, dtype: int64
```

If you really want to `groupby`, get the [`groupby.value_counts()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.value_counts.html) of all brands and select `Alfa Romeo`:

```
df.groupby('Vehicle Brand')['Reason of repair'].value_counts().loc['Alfa Romeo']

# Reason of repair
# Annual service        2
# Brakes not working    1
# Electrical issues     1
# Name: Reason of repair, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thanks heaps @tdy the second code works fine for this purpose! thank you!